# Abbreviating first names in the bibliography

Tags: citations, citation-style, personal-name

In my bibliography I use the names of the authors as they are given in the publication. Usually this will be the last name, the first name not abbreviated and second names abbreviated. However, I now have the following problems:

1. For some authors I only have publications with their first name abbreviated.
2. Some authors have their first name abbreviated in some publications and in others not. This leads to the strange result that I have them in the bibliography with their first name abbreviated only sometimes.

Should I try to get/use the not abbreviated first names for consistency or leave the names as they are given in the publications?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: It is certainly related to, if not a special case of [*Should I cite author names as they appear in the journal or as I know them to be complete?*](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10926/should-i-cite-author-names-as-they-appear-in-the-journal-or-as-i-know-them-to-be/10940)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm sorry I missed that one. However, the bottom line of the discussion in that post is a non consensus between "respect the authors choice", "be consistent in your own work" and "try to be as complete as possible". So I can decide now what's the best solution for me ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, thanks.  It is related, but I don't think it is an exact duplicate.

Comment: The busy person solution to retain consistency is **abbreviating everything**. Figuring out the first name of everyone you cite in your thesis takes a lot of time, for a very limited benefit.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, abbreviation vs full name might introduce ambiguities...

Comment: @vonbrand My bibliographies usually contain title, journal, issue, page numbers, author surnames and initials, and often a DOI. I don't think there is any room left for ambiguities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day this all boils down to opinion and you already gave the most important argument yourself: Usually, the only way to obtain consistency is to abbreviate all first names. If you try to use unabbreviated names even when the journal doesn’t, you will eventually run into a case where you cannot find out an author’s full first name by any reasonable means.

All journals that I am aware of adhere to such a citation style, so you would be in good company abbreviating first names. Moreover, such a citation style would not arise if it would lead to any practical problems. In fact, knowing an author’s full first name rarely accelerates finding a cited publication, and if then only by a little. I cannot imagine a situation where the first name would actually be necessary to find or identify a properly cited paper – you always have page numbers or similar to resolve potential ambiguities.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The only thing which is a bit more difficult when abbreviating first names is to search for the author lets say because you would like to find her/his academic website for further information. However, as the bibliography is not intended to be used in that way in the first place it's not an argument against abbreviation.